# Error: External table is not in the expected format

Tags: c#, excel

I used the below connection string to read excel file.

```
connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\test2.xlsx;Extended Properties=\'Excel 12.0;HDR=No;\";
```

While opening, an exception is thrown :

```
 "External table is not in the expected format"
```

I explored in several sites and changed the connection string as mentioned there and followed other solutions. But none of them didn't work.
Please guide me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are using this connection string, the actual code where you are trying to pull data

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/57cb3121-755d-4cd5-8cda-a0630cbf535b/microsoftaceoledb120-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format-error-on-windows-2003-server.

Comment: string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\test.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=NO\"";
using (connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
 connection.Open();  -------------At this line, I'm getting error        dataTable = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        DataView dataView = dataTable.DefaultView;
        dataView.Sort = "TABLE_NAME desc";
        dataTable = dataView.ToTable();
        connection.Close();
}

Comment: This should help you https://doubledotnet.wordpress.com/2013/07/29/reading-excel-sheet-to-datatable/